How to play this rhythm exercise?
Following up on my previous question, I am stating to work on my two handed rhythm.
I found a bunch of exercises that look like this:

I assume the right way to practice is to count the meter out loud and play the rhythm with both hands. Is that correct?
But then I got to this exercise:

Is this meant to played with three limbs? So tapping my foot?
Thanks!

It would be helpful to include the book's name, author, year, etc. where the exercises came from, which most likely would also include how you're supposed to do those exercises.  You also say in the title "How to play".  Do you ask how to do those exercises on the piano?  If it's for piano, you can use your left hand for the 3rd staff and combine both 1st and 2nd staff on the right hand as two voices.

It’s a PDF I found online which doesn’t have instructions.

Yes. For a three-staff exercise, tap your foot or vocalize the third part.
Sometimes I'll tap both feet (on different parts) and then clap the third part. In general with these exercises, the more parts of your body you can involve, the better. Meter and rhythm are both fundamentally physical experiences, to using your hands, feet, voice in various ways — tapping, walking, swinging, using different words/sounds/solfege — reinforces the learning.
Another thing I sometimes do when vocalizing is recite the alphabet (one letter per note) or lyrics to a song or some similar way of creating extra mental work for myself. It helps make sure you've internalized the rhythm enough to be able to think about additional things. In practice, those additional things would be dynamics, articulation, pitch, ..., all the various musical elements.

I might try using a four-mallet technique to practice a three (or four) part rhythm, but that's the only exception I can think of to your recommendation which is parts 3 and 4 go to the feet.

I wouldn't limit this to limbs (+voice) only. Another option is to use hand fingers, or even sections of body extremities. For instance, one part could be "played" by the base of the palm and the other with the fingers, or using external/internal parts of the hands (by rotating the wrist in case of alternation).

It wouldn't surprise me if later exercises used 4 lines.
That would be very similar to playing a drum kit. Top line, cymbal, next, snare, next bass drum, and lowest, hi-hat. Even though that's not how general drum music gets written out! All of which could be swapped around, to give some variety to the exercises.
It could be a great exercise, as using other limbs (and head!) often make rhythms easier to play and follow. Use whatever you like - shoulders, upper body, blowing raspberries: you decide.
